# error: a result was returned when none was expected exception postgres

Tags: postgresql, exception

I try to create a function and run it right after that. One i run them separately - both creation and running work. But not all together as a part of one long script - in that case I get "a result was returned when non was expected", despite the fact function returns void.

this is what I'm doing:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_calendar()
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare i date;
declare _error1 text;
begin
select max(day) into i from calendar;
if coalesce(i,'1900-01-01')<=date_trunc('day', now()) then 
  i:= '2013-01-01';
           WHILE i <= now()+'2 years'::interval
                LOOP 
              insert into calendar values (i);
              i := i+ '1 day'::interval;     
               END LOOP;               
end if;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN  _error1:=SQLSTATE;
   RETURN ;
END;
$function$
;
select  generate_calendar();
```

Comment: The whole function can be simplified to a simple `insert into calendar select i from generate_series(1, (select greatest(max(day), date_trunc('day', now()) from calendar))) as i`.

Comment: Thank you! Will change! Most of cases, this function will run to populate an empty table, that's why i need to set the "seed", that's why I used this way.

Comment: You should tell *how* you run the script. With psql? pgAdmin III? It looks suspiciously like something parses the statement, decides it is DDL and is surprised to get `PGRES_TUPLES_OK` instead of `PGRES_COMMAND_OK`.